# Central Control to Run Different Workbooks with Macros

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I was wondering if it was possible to create a control center with Access or Excel using VBA to run many different workbooks containing many different macros. I basically have 4-5 different workbooks that have different codes but instead of going into each workbook, I would like to run them all at once given they are all data pulls and formatting. I don't want to compile them into one workbook as that would be too messy and complicated.

What I have in mind is a macro button that would run all the different subs contained in many different workbooks. Someone help me be lazy (and efficient)!

Comment: This site isn't designed for the lazy programmer...[see this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Take a stab at coding it yourself and post back when/if you encounter issues or roadblocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the main workbook to open each workbook, complete the formatting and data pull, then save and close all of them, just with "one macro button".

Comment: Could you share a sample code? Would it be something like open then call sub? Just starting to get more familiar with VBA so will need some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Please keep in mind that you [should be asking specific questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that do not ask people to provide code for you. There are plenty of resources provided in a simple google search for opening other workbooks through vba, modifying them, and then closing them. If you get stuck while researching and have a specific question, then feel free to post another question.